# Cypher with clause unknown identifier `n` error.

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is my cypher query:

```
start n=node(*) match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n   
with count(n) as numbern ,count(r) as numberr 
where  HAS(n.taxnumber) and  numbern >= numberr 
return extract(s in `relationships(p) : s.amount), extract(t in nodes(p) : ID(t)), length(p); `
```

This gives me Unknown identifier `n` error. What is wrong with this? I use Neo4j 1.8.2 for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is no longer visible after your `WITH`,
`p` is also not visible then.

This query doesn't make any sense, what do you want to achieve with the aggregation?

Both counts return the same number btw.

Besides what we already discussed in the other issues, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make sure that in results I get the same number of nodes as I have relations - this could make sure I do not get connections to same nodes circled somehow more times. Right now as it is (I had the query where I removed start and end nodes as you know) but I get some nodes inside of the path circled twice - not the start nodes . If I would get the number of nodes and of relations in a path , make sure they are the same I would avoid results I do not need .

Comment: Since I am making a web application it may happen that I input that you owe me money and you may also input that you owe me money - so I get double inserted same relations , and when I run the query it circles around from you to me to someone else returns to me and goes to you - ok when it comes to logic but this is not what I want .

Comment: I added with p,n,r, count(distinct n) as numbern ,count(r) as numberr   where  HAS(n.taxnumber) and numbern=numberr  but againg I get doubles inside.

Comment: What I need as a result are closed geometrical figures , with how ever many relations and nodes but not two or more figures connected with a node that I am also getting.